# App crash cause firebase even without connexion why?

Tags: flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I don't understand this bug, before flutter nullsafety my app working great, but now I'm in flutter 2.0 and nullsafety several user have crash. After some days of using app. It's seems to be related to firebase but I request to test the app without internet connexion, but users have always crash.

Other possibility is this part of code who is call always before send data

```
 input=prefs.getKeys().map<String>((key) {
        return key + ":" + prefs.get(key).toString();
      }).toList();
```

This code call all key/value, from sharedpref, after this I send all data of user on firebase. Perhaps it's not a problem. but the fact, that the user crash even the connexion is OFF tel me, the read of lot of data with getkeys can produce a crash ... But I don't understant so why it's mentioned firestore on log. I have no log on crashanalitycs to point where the crash is, have juste this log.

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Internal error in Cloud Firestore (24.2.1).
           at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.AsyncQueue.lambda$panic$3(AsyncQueue.java:19)
           at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.-$$Lambda$AsyncQueue$jx84dqgUsF4ojecSMurRqFLFD1Y.run(-.java:2)
           at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:938)
           at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
           at android.os.Looper.loopOnce(Looper.java:226)
           at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:313)
           at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8663)
           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
           at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:571)
           at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1135)
    
   



Caused by java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.AsyncQueue$SynchronizedShutdownAwareExecutor.lambda$executeAndReportResult$1(AsyncQueue.java:14)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.-$$Lambda$AsyncQueue$SynchronizedShutdownAwareExecutor$pKSAgg-ozJ8RbUveSl-44aUfFQw.run(-.java:4)
       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:463)
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
       at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:307)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1137)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:637)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.AsyncQueue$SynchronizedShutdownAwareExecutor$DelayedStartFactory.run(AsyncQueue.java:15)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)



Caused by java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to get length of null array
       at com.google.protobuf.GeneratedMessageLite.parseFrom(GeneratedMessageLite.java)
       at com.google.firestore.v1.Write.parseFrom(Write.java:2)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.local.SQLiteDocumentOverlayCache.decodeOverlay(SQLiteDocumentOverlayCache.java)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.local.SQLiteDocumentOverlayCache.lambda$processOverlaysInBackground$5(SQLiteDocumentOverlayCache.java)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.local.SQLiteDocumentOverlayCache.lambda$processOverlaysInBackground$5$SQLiteDocumentOverlayCache(SQLiteDocumentOverlayCache.java)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.local.-$$Lambda$SQLiteDocumentOverlayCache$PNl4A-oJqX8nHYKTIlNfewPjqOU.run(-.java:8)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.-$$Lambda$PNiE7SuEFxRjAZH7pJpZIFOFjWg.execute(-.java)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.local.SQLiteDocumentOverlayCache.processOverlaysInBackground(SQLiteDocumentOverlayCache.java:23)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.local.SQLiteDocumentOverlayCache.lambda$processSingleCollection$1(SQLiteDocumentOverlayCache.java)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.local.SQLiteDocumentOverlayCache.lambda$processSingleCollection$1$SQLiteDocumentOverlayCache(SQLiteDocumentOverlayCache.java)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.local.-$$Lambda$SQLiteDocumentOverlayCache$cYi4Cr9jm_0SezP9UVaUuAt693w.accept(-.java:8)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.local.SQLitePersistence$Query.forEach(SQLitePersistence.java:13)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.local.SQLiteDocumentOverlayCache.processSingleCollection(SQLiteDocumentOverlayCache.java:54)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.local.SQLiteDocumentOverlayCache.getOverlays(SQLiteDocumentOverlayCache.java:78)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.local.LocalDocumentsView.populateOverlays(LocalDocumentsView.java:33)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.local.LocalDocumentsView.getOverlayedDocuments(LocalDocumentsView.java:9)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.local.LocalStore.lambda$writeLocally$2(LocalStore.java:55)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.local.LocalStore.lambda$writeLocally$2$LocalStore(LocalStore.java)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.local.-$$Lambda$LocalStore$cg_93_KSzr574nUI4weqpmjMR0A.get(-.java:8)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.local.SQLitePersistence.runTransaction(SQLitePersistence.java:20)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.local.LocalStore.writeLocally(LocalStore.java:42)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.core.SyncEngine.writeMutations(SyncEngine.java:7)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.core.FirestoreClient.lambda$write$12(FirestoreClient.java:2)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.core.FirestoreClient.lambda$write$12$FirestoreClient(FirestoreClient.java)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.core.-$$Lambda$FirestoreClient$EkV-69Na9I9DmQjVN9C_ABIfHUQ.run(-.java:6)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.AsyncQueue.lambda$enqueue$2(AsyncQueue.java)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.-$$Lambda$AsyncQueue$Y9GO7zO2DX6MzQJ5TbKtKW_NzO0.call(-.java:2)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.AsyncQueue$SynchronizedShutdownAwareExecutor.lambda$executeAndReportResult$1(AsyncQueue.java)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.-$$Lambda$AsyncQueue$SynchronizedShutdownAwareExecutor$pKSAgg-ozJ8RbUveSl-44aUfFQw.run(-.java:4)
       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:463)
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
       at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:307)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1137)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:637)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.AsyncQueue$SynchronizedShutdownAwareExecutor$DelayedStartFactory.run(AsyncQueue.java:15)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)

    Fatal Exception: i.b.a.b.i.b: Complete with: result l.b.m1.a$b@d06d159
           at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzw.zzh(zzw.java:5)
           at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzw.zza(zzw.java:8)
           at com.google.android.gms.tasks.zzz.run(zzz.java:27)
           at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.ThrottledForwardingExecutor.lambda$execute$0(ThrottledForwardingExecutor.java)
           at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.ThrottledForwardingExecutor.lambda$execute$0$ThrottledForwardingExecutor(ThrottledForwardingExecutor.java)
           at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.-$$Lambda$ThrottledForwardingExecutor$MfIJbVuxZtLwosAgPzPA-cU66Ko.run(-.java:4)
           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1137)
           at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:637)
           at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1012)
```

after firebase upgrade 24.2.2 I have this error

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Internal error in Cloud Firestore (24.2.2).
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.AsyncQueue.lambda$panic$3(AsyncQueue.java:19)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.-$$Lambda$AsyncQueue$jx84dqgUsF4ojecSMurRqFLFD1Y.run(-.java:2)
       at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:914)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:100)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:225)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7564)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:539)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950)


Caused by java.lang.RuntimeException: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteBlobTooBigException: Row too big to fit into CursorWindow requiredPos=0, totalRows=1
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.AsyncQueue$SynchronizedShutdownAwareExecutor.lambda$executeAndReportResult$1(AsyncQueue.java:14)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.-$$Lambda$AsyncQueue$SynchronizedShutdownAwareExecutor$pKSAgg-ozJ8RbUveSl-44aUfFQw.run(-.java:4)
       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:462)
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
       at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:301)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.AsyncQueue$SynchronizedShutdownAwareExecutor$DelayedStartFactory.run(AsyncQueue.java:15)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)


Caused by android.database.sqlite.SQLiteBlobTooBigException: Row too big to fit into CursorWindow requiredPos=0, totalRows=1
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.nativeExecuteForCursorWindow(SQLiteConnection.java)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteConnection.executeForCursorWindow(SQLiteConnection.java:942)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteSession.executeForCursorWindow(SQLiteSession.java:838)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteQuery.fillWindow(SQLiteQuery.java:62)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.fillWindow(SQLiteCursor.java:155)
       at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCursor.getCount(SQLiteCursor.java:142)
       at android.database.AbstractCursor.moveToPosition(AbstractCursor.java:232)
       at android.database.AbstractCursor.moveToNext(AbstractCursor.java:287)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.local.SQLitePersistence$Query.forEach(SQLitePersistence.java:5)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.local.SQLiteDocumentOverlayCache.processSingleCollection(SQLiteDocumentOverlayCache.java:54)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.local.SQLiteDocumentOverlayCache.getOverlays(SQLiteDocumentOverlayCache.java:78)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.local.LocalDocumentsView.populateOverlays(LocalDocumentsView.java:33)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.local.LocalDocumentsView.getOverlayedDocuments(LocalDocumentsView.java:9)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.local.LocalStore.lambda$writeLocally$2(LocalStore.java:55)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.local.LocalStore.lambda$writeLocally$2$LocalStore(LocalStore.java)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.local.-$$Lambda$LocalStore$cg_93_KSzr574nUI4weqpmjMR0A.get(-.java:8)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.local.SQLitePersistence.runTransaction(SQLitePersistence.java:20)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.local.LocalStore.writeLocally(LocalStore.java:42)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.core.SyncEngine.writeMutations(SyncEngine.java:7)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.core.FirestoreClient.lambda$write$12(FirestoreClient.java:2)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.core.FirestoreClient.lambda$write$12$FirestoreClient(FirestoreClient.java)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.core.-$$Lambda$FirestoreClient$EkV-69Na9I9DmQjVN9C_ABIfHUQ.run(-.java:6)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.AsyncQueue.lambda$enqueue$2(AsyncQueue.java)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.-$$Lambda$AsyncQueue$Y9GO7zO2DX6MzQJ5TbKtKW_NzO0.call(-.java:2)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.AsyncQueue$SynchronizedShutdownAwareExecutor.lambda$executeAndReportResult$1(AsyncQueue.java)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.-$$Lambda$AsyncQueue$SynchronizedShutdownAwareExecutor$pKSAgg-ozJ8RbUveSl-44aUfFQw.run(-.java:4)
       at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:462)
       at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
       at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:301)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
       at com.google.firebase.firestore.util.AsyncQueue$SynchronizedShutdownAwareExecutor$DelayedStartFactory.run(AsyncQueue.java:15)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:919)
```

Edit: after change

```
input = prefs.getKeys().map<String>((key) { 
                   return (key + ":" + prefs.get(key).toString());
                }).toList();
      });
```

I have this error

```
Caused by java.lang.RuntimeException
com.google.firebase.firestore.util.AsyncQueue$SynchronizedShutdownAwareExecutor.lambda$executeAndReportResult$1 (AsyncQueue.java:14)
com.google.firebase.firestore.util.-$$Lambda$AsyncQueue$SynchronizedShutdownAwareExecutor$pKSAgg-ozJ8RbUveSl-44aUfFQw.run (-.java:4)
java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call (Executors.java:457)
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run (FutureTask.java:266)
java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run (ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:301)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
com.google.firebase.firestore.util.AsyncQueue$SynchronizedShutdownAwareExecutor$DelayedStartFactory.run (AsyncQueue.java:15)
java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:784)



Caused by java.lang.IllegalStateException

android.database.CursorWindow.nativeGetBlob (CursorWindow.java)
android.database.CursorWindow.getBlob (CursorWindow.java:405)
android.database.AbstractWindowedCursor.getBlob (AbstractWindowedCursor.java:45)
com.google.firebase.firestore.local.SQLiteDocumentOverlayCache.processOverlaysInBackground (SQLiteDocumentOverlayCache.java:1)
com.google.firebase.firestore.local.SQLiteDocumentOverlayCache.lambda$processSingleCollection$1 (SQLiteDocumentOverlayCache.java)
com.google.firebase.firestore.local.SQLiteDocumentOverlayCache.lambda$processSingleCollection$1$SQLiteDocumentOverlayCache (SQLiteDocumentOverlayCache.java)
com.google.firebase.firestore.local.-$$Lambda$SQLiteDocumentOverlayCache$cYi4Cr9jm_0SezP9UVaUuAt693w.accept (-.java:8)
com.google.firebase.firestore.local.SQLitePersistence$Query.forEach (SQLitePersistence.java:13)
com.google.firebase.firestore.local.SQLiteDocumentOverlayCache.processSingleCollection (SQLiteDocumentOverlayCache.java:54)
com.google.firebase.firestore.local.SQLiteDocumentOverlayCache.getOverlays (SQLiteDocumentOverlayCache.java:78)
com.google.firebase.firestore.local.LocalDocumentsView.populateOverlays (LocalDocumentsView.java:33)
com.google.firebase.firestore.local.LocalDocumentsView.getOverlayedDocuments (LocalDocumentsView.java:9)
com.google.firebase.firestore.local.LocalStore.lambda$writeLocally$2 (LocalStore.java:55)
com.google.firebase.firestore.local.LocalStore.lambda$writeLocally$2$LocalStore (LocalStore.java)
com.google.firebase.firestore.local.-$$Lambda$LocalStore$cg_93_KSzr574nUI4weqpmjMR0A.get (-.java:8)
com.google.firebase.firestore.local.SQLitePersistence.runTransaction (SQLitePersistence.java:20)
com.google.firebase.firestore.local.LocalStore.writeLocally (LocalStore.java:42)
com.google.firebase.firestore.core.SyncEngine.writeMutations (SyncEngine.java:7)
com.google.firebase.firestore.core.FirestoreClient.lambda$write$12 (FirestoreClient.java:2)
com.google.firebase.firestore.core.FirestoreClient.lambda$write$12$FirestoreClient (FirestoreClient.java)
com.google.firebase.firestore.core.-$$Lambda$FirestoreClient$EkV-69Na9I9DmQjVN9C_ABIfHUQ.run (-.java:6)
com.google.firebase.firestore.util.AsyncQueue.lambda$enqueue$2 (AsyncQueue.java)
com.google.firebase.firestore.util.-$$Lambda$AsyncQueue$Y9GO7zO2DX6MzQJ5TbKtKW_NzO0.call (-.java:2)
com.google.firebase.firestore.util.AsyncQueue$SynchronizedShutdownAwareExecutor.lambda$executeAndReportResult$1 (AsyncQueue.java)
com.google.firebase.firestore.util.-$$Lambda$AsyncQueue$SynchronizedShutdownAwareExecutor$pKSAgg-ozJ8RbUveSl-44aUfFQw.run (-.java:4)
java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call (Executors.java:457)
java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run (FutureTask.java:266)
java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run (ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:301)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1162)
java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run (ThreadPoolExecutor.java:636)
com.google.firebase.firestore.util.AsyncQueue$SynchronizedShutdownAwareExecutor$DelayedStartFactory.run (AsyncQueue.java:15)
java.lang.Thread.run (Thread.java:784)
```

Here is related post. I think there is no solution ...
https://github.com/firebase/firebase-android-sdk/issues/208

Comment: Hi @Nitneuq, let me know if you tried the change in input fragment,did it work for you.

Comment: I upgrade my post after change (key + ":" + prefs.get(key).toString());  always crash with firebase.

Answer (score 0):

As the exceptions  here seem to be of various types,so you will have to look at this one at a time and try and eliminate the probable cause.
The first error or rather an exception thrown as below indicates a run time issue occurred with Cloud Firestore, this also could be possible due to a function call during the program run which looks for something associated with the Cloud Firestore and failed as  you mentioned there was no connection.
I would recommend it if you possibly upgrade to [Cloud Firestore version 24.2.2](https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android#firestore_v24-2-2) and see as it comes with a fix for waiting for pending writes which could cause NullPointer exceptions too.

`Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Internal error in Cloud Firestore (24.2.1).`

The second exception thrown here is sometimes a very common java exception usually occurring due to an attempt to use a `null` as if it was a real reference .Also check if you are you are using an object without initializing it.Have a look at the [Best Practice to avoid NullPointer exception](https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2013/05/ava-tips-and-best-practices-to-avoid-nullpointerexception-program-application.html#axzz7cxfVzudO).

You can try out using below fragment :

```
     input = prefs.getKeys().map<String>((key) { 
                   return (key + ":" + prefs.get(key).toString());
                }).toList();
      });
```

Instead of

```
input=prefs.getKeys().map<String>((key) {
        return key + ":" + prefs.get(key).toString();
      }).toList();
```

Comment: I have always error with Firestore (24.2.2) => Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Internal error in Cloud Firestore (24.2.2). but it seems diferent I update post. I will try (key + ":" + prefs.get(key).toString()); for the next release test